# Eclipse search with exlcusions

Tags: eclipse

Is there a simple way to search for something in eclipse and add exceptions ?

So I would like to search for override and exclude occurrences of @override in all *.java files.  I see you can use !x in the filename patterns but not in the containing text.  Is this something I would need to do with a regex search or is there a simple way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must check "Regular Expression" and then write some like this:

**^((?!keyword).)*$**

This expression is similar to NOT.

I hope that this help you.

[image]

Comment: Yes thanks.  I'll look at ding regex searches, I'm not sure how I've got along so long without having to learn it properly...